# How to parse a "here document" in Python?

Tags: python, heredoc

I want to write a Python method that reads a text file with key-values:

```sh
FOO=BAR
BUZ=BLEH
```

I also want to support newlines either through quoting and `\n`, and by supporting [here-docs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document):

```sh
MULTILINE1="This\nis a test"
MULTILINE2= <<DOC
This
is a test
DOC
```

While the first one is easy to implement, I'm struggling with the second. Is there maybe something in Python's stdlib (i.e. [shlex](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/shlex.html)) that I can use already?

Answer (score 1):

**"test.txt" content:**

```
FOO=BAR
BUZ=BLEH
MULTILINE1="This\nis a test"
MULTILINE2= <<DOC
This
is a test
DOC
```

**Function:**

```
def read_strange_file(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        file_content = f.read().splitlines()

    res = {}
    key, value, delim = "", "", ""
    for line in file_content:
        if "=" in line and not delim:
            key, value = line.split("=")
            if value.strip(" ").startswith("<<"):
                delim = value.strip(" ")[2:] # extracting delimiter keyword
                value = ""
                continue
        if not delim or (delim and line == delim):
            if value.startswith("\"") and value.endswith("\""):
                # [1: -1] delete quotes
                value = bytes(value[1: -1], "utf-8").decode("unicode_escape") 
            if delim:
                value = value[:-1] # delete "\n"
            res[key] = value
            delim = ""
        if delim:
            value += line + "\n"

    return res
```

**Usage:**

```
result = read_strange_file("test.txt")
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'FOO': 'BAR', 'BUZ': 'BLEH', 'MULTILINE1': 'This\nis a test', 'MULTILINE2': 'This\nis a test'}
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm assuming that this is the test string (i.e., there are unseen `\n` characters at the end of each line):

```py
s = ''
s += 'MULTILINE1="This\nis a test"\n'
s += 'MULTILINE2= <<DOC\n'
s += 'This\n'
s += 'is a test\n'
s += 'DOC\n'
```

The best I can do is to cheat using NumPy:

```py
import numpy as np

A  = np.asarray([ss.rsplit('\n', 1)  for ss in ('\n'+s).split('=')])
keys   = A[:-1,1].tolist()
values = A[1:,0].tolist()

#optionally parse here-documents
di     = 'DOC' #delimiting identifier
values = [v.strip().lstrip('<<%s\n'%di).rstrip('\n%s'%di) for v in values]

print('Keys: ', keys)
print('Values: ', values)

#if you want a dictionary:
d      = dict( zip(keys, values) )
```

This results in:

```
Keys:  ['MULTILINE1', 'MULTILINE2']
Values:  ['"This\nis a test"', '"This\nis a test"']
```

It works by sneakily adding a `\n` character to the beginning of the string, then splitting the whole string by `=` characters, then finally uses  `rsplit` to retain all values to the right of `=`, even when those values contain multiple `\n` characters. Printing the array `A` makes things clearer:

```
[['',                             'MULTILINE1'],
 ['"This\nis a test"',            'MULTILINE2'],
 [' <<DOC\nThis\nis a test\nDOC', ''         ]]
```

Comment: There is multiline string in python. `"""I can be multiline"""` ;) Check [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

Comment: Yes, I've pointed you because of first part of your response.

Comment: By the way, when you write `"\n"` in python it doesn't mean literally `"\n"`. Python will convert it to line break automatically. If you want it to be `"\n"` you should write `"\\n"`. And at all, your answer doesn't solve problem of author.

Comment: I've pointed you to docs. Try to read them. To make `\n` characters "clear" you may use `"This is string\n"`. Your answer doens't solve problem of author because: 1) your input data is not correct 2) you doesn't parse "here-docs" format 3) there's dict in python, which have been created to store data in format key-value, you use 2 separate lists instead 4) because of first reason it won't work with file content.

Comment: I appreciate you efforts, but you should check again what "here-doc" format is. Your code still not parse it. And input still wrong.

Comment: Cause if you change `DOC` to `DOG` your code will not parse it.

Comment: But your code will not parse author's input correctly, cause your input is not same.

Comment: `"\n"` - is line break (depends on OS it could be `\n`, `\r`, `\r\n`). `"\\n"` - is string with 2 chars "\" and "n". It's not the same. Also there is other characters which can be escaped (e.g. `\t`). If you'll write `print("Hello, this is\nQuouted\t\t\tstring")` It will print 2 lines with 3 tabs in second whether `print(Hello, this is\\nQuouted\\t\\t\\tstring)` will print one line without any formatting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193091/discussion-between-toddp-and-olvin-roght).